# Dual-booting Ubuntu with un-activated version of Windows XP?

Tags: installation, dual-boot, windows, toshiba

My sister wants to install Ubuntu on her Toshiba Satellite, which is a few years old.  Problem is, her copy of Windows XP is not activated, and whenever she tries to activate it, she is told by that her activation number is invalid.

So, would she still be able to install Ubuntu on her computer?  Also, I already have a 4-Gb flash-drive, but where would I find the installation files?

Answer (score 0):

Download Ubuntu: http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop

Download Live Linux USB Creator: http://www.linuxliveusb.com/

1. Put the thumb drive in the computer.
2. Launch Live Linux USB Creator
3. Select the Ubuntu .ISO image
4. Start the OS image creation
5. Reboot computer, F8 into BIOS and select USB as first boot device and install

Comment: Thank you all for the help!  I've never installed an OS before, so I was kind of confused.  Seems pretty simple.

Answer (score 0):

> So, would she still be able to install Ubuntu on her computer?

Ubuntu doesn't care about the status of the Activation of Windows.

> Also, I already have a 4-Gb flash-drive, but where would I find the installation files?

If you already created an installation USB (it contains a bunch of files), just reboot your system, enter in the BIOS (this varies in each system), change the boot order (again, this varies) to put the USB first, save the changes and there you go.